# How to create a pivot table in BigQuery without using case statement

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a sample table as below -

```
with temp as 
(
select 1 as id, 'first' as grade, 'mango' as q1_which_fruit_do_you_like union all
select 2 as id, 'second' as grade, 'apple' as q1_which_fruit_do_you_like union all
select 3 as id, 'third' as grade, 'banana' as q1_which_fruit_do_you_like union all
select 4 as id, 'first' as grade, 'mango' as q1_which_fruit_do_you_like union all
select 5 as id, 'second' as grade, 'apple' as q1_which_fruit_do_you_like union all
select 6 as id, 'third' as grade, 'banana' as q1_which_fruit_do_you_like union all
select 7 as id, 'first' as grade, 'mango' as q1_which_fruit_do_you_like union all
select 8 as id, 'second' as grade, 'apple' as q1_which_fruit_do_you_like union all
select 9 as id, 'third' as grade, 'banana' as q1_which_fruit_do_you_like
)

select *
from temp
```

[image]

I want to create a pivot table from this table so that I can count how many people in which grade like which fruit. It is possible to do using case statement but I want to look for a generic solution because my table has 100 such question columns and each record has 1 of the X options for the question to choose from. But I want to do this on 1 column before I scale it to rest.

The sample output in this case would be -
[image: sample]

How do I achieve this using bigquery and without a case statement? do structs or arrays help ?

Comment: Pivoting is not an easy job, check the fast approach here https://corecompete.com/how-to-build-pivot-tables-in-bigquery-fast-and-easy/. Sadly, one manual part of picking all the columns could be needed

Comment: Do you consider to use (or import and maintain) a procedure for PIVOT https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65948834/pivot-in-bigquery/65950410#65950410